# Objeto depois de persistido e retornado inconsistente para uma dropdown list

Tags: java-ee, spring-mvc, spring-data

Olá pessoal boa tarde!

Bem, resumidamente tenho um problema no qual não faço ideia do que pode estar acontecendo. Na minha opnião não faz sentido tal comportamento.

Estou usando Spring MVC + Spring Data para facilitar as operações de CRUD em meu sistema. Tenho uma pagina na qual eu realizo um cadastro de categorias, trata-se de algo simples, apenas um campo "name" e outro para verificar se a categoria esta ou não ativa.

Em seguida tenho uma "Gestão de Destinos", quem tem como objetivo cadastro de novos destinos. Nele tenho uma associação com categoria na qual é populada um componente de dropdown list. Tal relacionanmento e do fator OneToOne unidirecional.

O componente é populado normalmente, abaixo o codigo do mesmo:

**View:**

```
<f:select path="categories.idCategory">
    <f:option value="-1" label="-- Selecione uma categoria para associação --"/>
    <f:options items="${categoryDropDown}" itemValue="idCategory" itemLabel="ctName"/>
</f:select>
```

**Controller:**

```
//Entra na tela de cadastro de um novo destino
@RequestMapping("newDestination")
public ModelAndView setnewDestination(Model model, HttpServletRequest req){
    //Inicializa o Componente DropDown de Categoria
    List<Category> category = dashboardFacade.getCategoryList();
    List<Category> activeCategory = new ArrayList<Category>();

    //Verificação de categorias que não estão ativas
    for (Category allCAtegory : category) {
        if(allCAtegory.getCtActive() == 1){ 
            activeCategory.add(allCAtegory);
        }
    }
    model.addAttribute("categoryDropDown", activeCategory);

    return new ModelAndView("destination/newDestination", "command", new Destination());
}
```

**Facade:**

```
public List<Category> getCategoryList(){
    return categoryRepository.findAll();
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends BaseRepository<Category, Long>{

    List<Category> findAll();

}
```

Bem, o que ocorre na realidade é que quando eu vou cadastrar um novo destino e seleciono uma categoria o mesmo e salvo com sucesso na base. Mas quando eu tenho cadastra novamente um destino a minha `List<Category> category = dashboardFacade.getCategoryList();` vem com objeto inconsistente. Ou seja, com valores null.

Objeto category populando a dropbox sem sua associação ter sido salva:

- [idCategory=1, ctActive=1, ctName=Nacional, tenantId=2],
- [idCategory=2, ctActive=0, ctName=Internacional, tenantId=2],
- [idCategory=3, ctActive=1, ctName=Cruzeiro, tenantId=2],
- [idCategory=4, ctActive=1, ctName=Espacial, tenantId=2],

Salvei um novo destino com a categoria de nome "Nacional". Quando o dropdown ela simplesmente não aparece.
Este é o estado que category é encntrado:

- [idCategory=1, ctActive=0, ctName=null, tenantId=null],
- [idCategory=2, ctActive=0, ctName=Internacional, tenantId=2],
- [idCategory=3, ctActive=1, ctName=Cruzeiro, tenantId=2],
- [idCategory=4, ctActive=1, ctName=Espacial, tenantId=2],

Não faço ideia do que pode estar ocorrendo.

Se alguém puder ajudar fico muito grato.

Abraço a todos

**EDIÇÃO**

Abaixo seguem os mapeamentos:

*Destination.java*

```
package br.com.joocebox.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Multitenant;
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.TenantDiscriminatorColumn;
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.PersistenceUnitProperties;
/**
 * The persistent class for the destination database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="destination")
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name="tenant_id", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, contextProperty=PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
@NamedQuery(name="Destination.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM Destination d")
public class Destination implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_destination")
    private Long idDestination;

    @Column(name="tenant_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long tenantId;

    @Column(name="active")
    private byte dtActive;

    @Column(name="appear_website")
    private Boolean dtAppearWebsite;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="description")
    private String dtDescription;

    @Column(name="highlight_website")
    private Boolean dtHighlightWebsite;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String dtName;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_streetview")
    private StreetView streetView;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_video")
    private Video video;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_category")
    private Category categories;

//  //bi-directional many-to-one association to Agency
//  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
//  @JoinColumn(name="fk_agency")
//  private Agency agency;

    //Profiles of System. These profiles are all enum type.
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_economic")
    private EconomicProfile economicProfiles;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_general")
    private GeneralProfile generalProfiles;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_social")
    private SocialProfile socialProfiles;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_trip")
    private TripProfile tripProfiles;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_weather")
    private WeatherProfile weatherprofile;
    //End of Profiles of System.

//  @OneToMany(mappedBy="destination")
//  private Set<Image> images;

    public Destination() {
    }

    public Long getIdDestination() {
        return this.idDestination;
    }

//Getter and Setters
}
```

**Category.java**

```
package br.com.joocebox.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;


import javax.persistence.*;

import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.Multitenant;
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.TenantDiscriminatorColumn;
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.PersistenceUnitProperties;
/**
 * The persistent class for the category database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name="tenant_id", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, contextProperty=PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
@NamedQuery(name="Category.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Category c")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_category")
    private Long idCategory;

    @Column(name="ct_active")
    private int ctActive;

    @Column(name="ct_name")
    private String ctName;

    @Column(name="tenant_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long tenantId;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Long getIdCategory() {
        return this.idCategory;
    }

//Getters and Setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category [idCategory=" + idCategory + ", ctActive=" + ctActive
                + ", ctName=" + ctName + ", tenantId=" + tenantId + "]";
    }



}
```

Obrigado!

---

filipeportes,

não funcionou. Na verdade não sei mais o que pode ser.

Fiz desta forma:

**Category.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name="tenant_id", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, contextProperty=PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
@NamedQuery(name="Category.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Category c")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_category")
    private Long idCategory;

    @Column(name="ct_active")
    private int ctActive;

    @Column(name="ct_name")
    private String ctName;

    @Column(name="tenant_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long tenantId;

    //Relacionamento com Category
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="categories", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Destination> destination;

    //Getters and Setters
```

**Destination.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="destination")
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name="tenant_id", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, contextProperty=PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
@NamedQuery(name="Destination.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM Destination d")
public class Destination implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_destination")
    private Long idDestination;

    @Column(name="tenant_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long tenantId;

    @Column(name="active")
    private byte dtActive;

    @Column(name="appear_website")
    private Boolean dtAppearWebsite;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="description")
    private String dtDescription;

    @Column(name="highlight_website")
    private Boolean dtHighlightWebsite;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String dtName;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_streetview")
    private StreetView streetView;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_video")
    private Video video;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_category")
    private Category categories;

    //Getters and Setters
```

Parece que fica algo em cache, pois quando eu dou um shutdown e subo novamente o server meu objeto vem de forma consistente.

Abraço

Comment: pode adicionar os mapeamentos de suas classes de modelo por favor?

Comment: @filipeportes Editei a pergunta com os mapeamentos correwspondentes. Obrigado!

Comment: não sei se isso tem relação com o problema, mas não vejo necessidade de utilizar o mapeamento OneToOne no seu caso, use ele apenas se precisar do mapeamento inverso, ou seja, de Destination dentro de Category.

Answer (score 1):

isso pode ter relação com o problema, não vejo necessidade de utilizar o mapeamento `@OneToOne` no seu caso, use ele apenas se precisar do mapeamento inverso, ou seja, de Destination dentro de Category. 
prefira sempre utilizar o `@ManyToOne` e evite ao máximo mapeamento inverso.

Outra boa prática é utilizar SEMPRE o `fetch=FetchType.LAZY`, os mapeamentos `@OneToOne` e `@ManyToOne` tem como default o fetch EAGER, ou seja, carrega todos os dados mapeados do banco mesmo que não sejam utilizados, isso pode gerar problemas graves de performance.